# Get value on redis expiration notification

Tags: redis

Is it possible to get the value associated with a key when the expiration [notification](http://redis.io/topics/notifications) is thrown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to get the value of the key in the notification event.

Comment: Further background on why this isn't a good idea to implement in Redis: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/1876